# Why do we need both DHCPOFFER and DHCPREQUEST?

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server

In DHCP DORA process, the server offers a client an IP address with DHCPOFFER message. Why does the client have to send an explicit DHCPREQUEST message again to the server? Why not send a DHCPACCEPT message there itself and get an IP address?

I think the need for both the messages makes sense if multiple DHCP servers are offering IP addresses to a client. The client can choose any one of the IPs offered and then the remaining servers will withdraw their offer. But what if my environment has only 1 DHCP server instead?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: it's just a matter of naming. Think of DHCPREQUEST as your DHCPACCEPT and you'll see they are doing the same thing.

The server behaviour is specified in [RFC 2131](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2131#page-26). The message pairs are:

```
DHCPDISCOVER -> DHCPOFFER
DHCPREQUEST -> DHCPACK
```

You propose adding a new DHCPACCEPT message that would do exactly what DHCPREQUEST does now (note that you should still set the 'xid', timestamp ...). And that new message should still fit in the request-response type of protocol DHCP belongs to so you would end up with something like:

```
DHCPDISCOVER -> DHCPOFFER
DHCPACCEPT -> DHCPACK
```

What would be the advantage? You still need DHCPACK (that's the message that actually sets the adress, see the [state diagram for the client](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2131#page-34)).

It would be just a new type of message (like adding a DHCPEXTENDLEASE, it could be easier to read, but you add possible states and transitions for no real gain). Both the theoretical DHCPACCEPT and DHCPEXTENDLEASE are already handled by DHCPREQUEST. They take the offer from the server, add some fields (an important step) and accept it. And then **have** to wait for the server to confirm it.